# Postgres: update the column with lowest value

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table with the following structure (last_seen[1,2] are timestamps):

```
EVENT_ID | last_seen1 | last_seen2
-----------------------------------
    2    |   120660   | 123400
```

I want to know the latest 2 times where an event happened. In a traditional way, I should keep the most recent timestamp in last_seen1, and write the older value in last_seen2. When a new event will arrive, i have to move the value from last_seen1 to last_seen2 and write a new value in last_seen1.

But I wonder if it's possible to do the following: when EVENT_ID = 2 will come again, I want to **update the column with the lowest value**. I don't know WHERE is the oldest timestamp, the query should be written in a so smart way, that it will discover the name of the column with the lowest value (between the two candidate columns: last_seen1, last_seen2).

Reading from such table is simple, because i can use MIN or MAX of values in last_seen[1,2].
But how to create a query to WRITE the column with the lowest value, if this is possible?
I mean, i don't know if the name of the column where i am going to write: it can be last_seen1 or last_seen2.

Comment: Note: these columns are *not* timestamps, but numbers.

Comment: Timestamps are numbers :) Anyway, I wrote those values manually, as examples. They are too much "early" timestamps :) to happen today

Comment: No, timestamps are **not**  "numbers". `2020-18-08 09:41:57` is a timestamp. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: Sorry to disagree: a timestamp is of type `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamp without timezone`. I harp on that because there is a sad fashion to model timestamps as integers, which makes queries hard to understand and more complicated than necessary, because you lose the power of datetime operators and functions.

Comment: The timestamp should be without timezone in my server. The client will read and print according its timezone, so that the server does not need to know where the client will be. I mean the so called Unix timestamp = the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT).
See https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the logic of `CASE WHEN` expressions for this, and remember that overwriting a value with itself is harmless:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET last_seen1 = CASE WHEN last_seen1 < last_seen2 THEN 'newvalue' ELSE last_seen1 END,
    last_seen2 = CASE WHEN last_seen1 < last_seen2 THEN last_seen2 ELSE 'newvalue' END
WHERE event_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **LEAST** to get the values:

```
SELECT LEAST(last_seen1, last_seen2) FROM  t WHERE event=2
```

or with **GREATEST**

```
UPDATE t SET last_seen1=LEAST(last_seen1, last_seen2), last_seen2=GREATEST(last_seen1, last_seen2) WHERE event=2;
```

or with desired *newvalue*

```
UPDATE t SET last_seen1=LEAST(last_seen1, last_seen2, newvalue), last_seen2=GREATEST(last_seen1, last_seen2, newvalue) WHERE event=2;
```

Comment: I think it's quite clear, see carefully the second paragraph under the table sample. I can be more clear in italian, in english i can't do better.